# Android jsoup "Unfortunately Stop"

Tags: android, jsoup

I have problem with jsoup. Every time I run application I got `Unfortunately Stop`. I tried all the ways and still getting it. I don't know what the wrong and this is simple from the code and I tried thread and didn't worked.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {        
    String result;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new MyInnerClass().execute();
    }

    private class MyInnerClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {      

           @Override
           protected void onPreExecute() {
           super.onPreExecute();    
           }

           @Override
           protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try{

            Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://google.come").get();
            }catch(Exception e){Log.d("doinbackground exception", e.toString());}
           return "Done";
           }

           @Override
           protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);
            final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText(result);
           }
        }
        }
```

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: i dont see any textview declared  tv.setText(result)

Answer (score 0):

Make correction here

```
@Override
           protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);
            final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            tv.setText(result);
           }
```

First the get the tv from your activity_main layout and than do setText to it

```
TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextIDDefinedIn activity_main); 
tv.setText(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution :

Press check box for android jsoup in :

(properties --> Java build path --> Order and export) .

Thanks guys.